# How to change only the current (this) element inside a loop with useState in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onmouseover

I'm struggling to achieve this.
When onMouseOver, ALL the images are changing class and showing the content. I want only the current element, where the mouse is over, to be changed. Any idea how to achieve this? I already tried a lot of things.

If I could use something like:
onMouseOver={() => THIS.setShowContent("showContent")}
But I can't!

Thanks a lot!
CODE:

```
import classes from "./style.module.scss";

export default function ProjectsComponent() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [showContent, setShowContent] = useState("dontShowContent");

  useEffect(() => {
    let arrayAux = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
      arrayAux.push(
        <div className={[classes.images, classes[`image${i}`]].join(" ")}>
          <div className={classes.showBackground}></div>
        </div>
      );
    }
    setImages(arrayAux);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.containerProjects}>
      <div className={classes.grid}>
        {images.map((imageDiv, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            onMouseOver={() => setShowContent("showContent")}
            onMouseLeave={() => setShowContent("dontShowContent")}
            className={classes.imgBox}
          >
            <div className={classes[showContent]}>IMAGE {index} CONTENT</div>
            <div className={classes.onHover}>{imageDiv}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Storing JSX in state is a react anti-pattern. Functional components also have no `this` to use. You have only one single `showContent` state, you need to associate one with each element you want to toggle. Alternatively you can convert the elements you want hoverable to react components (or create a `withHover` HOC) so they each have their own managed hover state.

Comment: Also, I recommend using CSS as much as possible for showing/hiding an element. You can completely avoid JS if this is all you want to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Drew! I will read about "Storing JSX in state is a react anti-pattern".
About the CSS to show and hide, I generally do it, but this example is a bit more complex. I'm hiding and showing different things with different positions on hovering the same element. Thanks a lot for your message!

Comment: I've helped resolve multiple mouse enter/exit, over/leave issues and when using JS there  *always* seem to be edge cases or performance issues that occasionally crop up and leave the ui in a "hovered" state. CSS mostly avoids this as it happens outside the JS event loop & processing.

Answer (score 3):

What I will suggest is you have to add something unique between each element inside the `images map`.
So one way is to make use of another state variable to keep track of current active image to show content `on hover`.
So you can make use of `index` to set `activeImage`. and then compare the `index` and `activeImage` state variable to check is a current and active(hovered) image using its index and then only apply `show content` class.

```
const [activeImage, setActiveImage] = useState(-1);
```

```
{images.map((imageDiv, index) => (
          <div
            key={index}
            onMouseOver={() =>{ 
              setShowContent("showContent");
              setActiveImage(index);
             }}
            onMouseLeave={() => {
             setShowContent("dontShowContent");
             setActiveImage(-1);
             }}
            className={classes.imgBox}
          >
            <div className={index === activeImage && classes[showContent]}>IMAGE {index} CONTENT</div>
            <div className={classes.onHover}>{imageDiv}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
```

Let me know if it doesn't work in your case or if I am misleading here.

Comment: Dear Sagar! Thank you sooooo much!!! I just had to add another condition and it worked PERFECTLY! I added: index === activeImage && classes[showContent]) || classes.dontShowContent. You made my day!